# Visual Studio 2017 Mac Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I've managed to install Entity Framework on Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac as a Nuget Package. However, when I try to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model, I can't. I only see options to add files.